# When to use Gateway design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

while trying to get my head into some design patterns I've run across a sample that confuses me - hopefully it something easy to explain, and I'm just missing it.

my question is "where" does gateway fit into this? it seems redundant, as an added data access point.

the sample code has three classes -

1. `person` - which has getter and setter methods for each of the objects attributes
2. `personDAO` - which has data calls to do the CRUD.
3. `personGateway` - which has `getAll` and `getCount` - which are data calls too...???

I totally get making a DAO call for data, and the DAO uses the "person" class to create an object to pass back - but WHY NOT put the `getAll` and `getCount` in the DAO???

What LOGICAL position does the "gateway" play in this game?

--- added after reading responses ---

Ok - I apparently missed this while searching - and it does "help" clarify -
[Need some clarification with Patterns (DAO x Gateway)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810020/need-some-clarification-with-patterns-dao-x-gateway) - HOWEVER, it seem very java centric and it actually skips the distinction I was hoping for -

I guess the answer is that DAO returns an "object" and an "object" is a single entity...not a collection. If you're retuning a collection (and it's debatable if you "should") then you'd use the gateway... but under no circumstance should you muddy the DAO with collections...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need some clarification with Patterns (DAO x Gateway)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810020/need-some-clarification-with-patterns-dao-x-gateway)

Comment: This is discussed nicely here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810020/need-some-clarification-with-patterns-dao-x-gateway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Gateway Pattern**

> A gateway encapsulates the semantic gap between the object-oriented
>   domain layer and the relation-oriented persistence layer.

Definition taken from [here](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/persistence/gateway.htm).

The Gateway in your example is also called a "Service". The service layer is important because it provides a higher abstraction and a more "holistic" way in dealing with a Person entity.

The reason for this "extra" layer is the other objects in the system that are connected to a Person. For example, say there are `Car` objects and each Person may have a Car. Now, when we sell a car we should update the "owner" field, further you'll want to do the same for the Person objects that are involved (seller/buyer).

In order to achieve this "cascading" in an OO manner (without coupling the objects implementations) `BuyCarService` will update the new owners: the service will call `CarDAO` and `PersonDAO` in order to update the relevant fields in the DB so that the DAOs won't have to "know" each other and hence decouple the implementations.

Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: interestingly - it confuses things a bit more - simply because there was a "personService" in the example - that I did not include because I wanted to grasp "gateway" first - and it was pretty clear that "service" (in this example) was all remote calls to ANY of the methods in DAO or Gateway (again - in this example) so, by saying gateway IS service - it does confuse the issue, but I'll try make it all fit by reading all the suggestions above and distil all the info - thx.

Comment: @jpmyob according to different sources I read, GW pattern and Service have the same purpose. I added the definition of GW to the answer. It could be that there are other examples in which GW is not a service but it is still being used in order to encapsulate (hide) what happens "behind the scenes". Even if you run into an example where the GW looks totally redundant - it is still a good idea to have it since the nature of products is to develop and become more complex and we should plan for the future and design our code to be abstract and generic so it'll be easy to add features when needed.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the Design patterns explanations become confusing at some time or other because originally it was named and explained by someone but in due course of time several other similar patterns come into existence which have similar usage and explanation but very little difference. This subtle difference then becomes a source of debates:-). Concerning Gateway pattern, here is what is Martin Fowler mentions in Catalogs of Enterprise Application architecture.I am straight quoting from [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html)

> "Gateway - An object that encapsulates access to an external system or
>   resource."
>
> Interesting software rarely lives in isolation. Even the purest
>   object-oriented system often has to deal with things that aren't
>   objects, such as relational data-base tables, CICS transactions, and
>   XML data structures.
>
> When accessing external resources like this, you'll usually get APIs
>   for them. However, these APIs are naturally going to be somewhat
>   complicated because they take the nature of the resource into account.
>   Anyone who needs to under-stand a resource needs to understand its API
>   - whether JDBC and SQL for rela-tional databases or W3C or JDOM for XML. Not only does this make the software harder to understand, it
>   also makes it much harder to change should you shift some data from a
>   relational database to an XML message at some point in the future.
>
> The answer is so common that it's hardly worth stating. Wrap all the
>   special API code into a class whose interface looks like a regular
>   object. Other objects access the resource through this Gateway, which
>   translates the simple method calls into the appropriate specialized
>   API.

Answer (score 0):

The **Gateway design pattern** is useful when you want to work with a complex SDK, Library or API. To work with them you may need some implementation that lower layers don't have to know about them and of course, that is not important for other layers. In this case, the Gateway design pattern is the best solution. Yo implement what you want with any SDK or library and after that with a contract, other project layers can work easily with the gateway. And if someday you decide to change the mentioned SDK or API, it doesn't affect to the whole of the project. You simply can change the gateway implementation and the contract will be unchanged for the other layers.